# Add data to mongodb at run time

Tags: json, mongodb

I am relatively new to both mongodb and json. My query is i am getting certain data from a buffer and would like to add this data to my database. how can i save my data dynamically in my mongodb database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Shikha,

Here's what you can do,

- Create Collection to hold the data
- Use insert query to insert the data. => [Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)